# No se puede abrir la consola en Visual Studio Code

Tags: vscode

No me deja abrir la consola en Visual Studio Code, me sale este error, ya intente desinstalando el programa e instalarlo de nuevo pero sigue sin abrirlo, alguna idea?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

El problema que comentas me lo he encontrado en alguna ocasión. La solución que yo he aplicado es indicándole al VSCode la ruta dónde se encuentra la consola que quiero usar.

- Abre el archivo settings.json (Ctrl+,)
- Cambia la visualización para ver el archivo en formato texto
- Introduce la siguiente línea:

```json
"terminal.external.windowsExec":"${env:windir}\\system32\\cmd.exe"
```

Esto te debería permitir usar el clásico `cmd` como consola.
Si desear usar otra consola como gitbash, powershell..., deberá indicar la ruta a su ejecutable:

- GITBash => "terminal.external.windowsExec": "${env:programfiles}\Git\bin\bash.exe"

> Ten en cuenta que estos ejemplos son con rutas para Windows, si usas otro sistema operativo deberás adaptar estas líneas. Para Linux la configuración es "terminal.external.linuxExec", mientras que para MAC sería "terminal.external.osxExec"